# How to read multiple variables from a file in Clojure?

Tags: file, loops, dictionary, clojure, lisp

Coming from OOP, I'm having a bit of trouble adjusting to the immutability of Clojure.

What I want to do is grab some variables from a file, and store each variable and its data to a map.

In other words, I want to 'extract' a map from a text file.

As an example, the file would look like this:

```
username: michael
password: foo123
email: barfoo@gmail.com
```

My question is, how do I convert the above file into a map like this: (?)

```
{:username "michael", :password "foo123", :email "barfoo@gmail.com"}
```

This is what I had so far, but I have no idea how to get multiple variables:

```
(with-open [rdr (reader "/path/to/file.txt")]
  (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
    // make map here somehow? ))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(->> (clojure.string/split (slurp "yourfile.txt") #"\n")
     (map #(clojure.string/split % #":"))
     (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) v]))
     (into {}))
```

`slurp` function read a file and returns a string of file contents. It's useful to read text file into a string. After that, split the string by `\n`, which retrun a sequence of strings. Then split each string by `:`.

You can check each step in the REPL and see the result of each step, like this:

```
user=> (->> (clojure.string/split (slurp "yourfile.txt") #"\n"))
["username: michael" "password: foo123" "email: barfoo@gmail.com"]
user=> (->> (clojure.string/split (slurp "yourfile.txt") #"\n")
            (map #(clojure.string/split % #":\s*")))
(["username" "michael"] ["password" "foo123"] ["email" "barfoo@gmail.com"])
user=> (->> (clojure.string/split (slurp "yourfile.txt") #"\n")
            (map #(clojure.string/split % #":\s*"))
            (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) v])))
([:username "michael"] [:password "foo123"] [:email "barfoo@gmail.com"])
user=> (->> (clojure.string/split (slurp "yourfile.txt") #"\n")
            (map #(clojure.string/split % #":\s*"))
            (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) v]))
            (into {}))
{:username "michael", :password "foo123", :email "barfoo@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked and taught me quite a bit! Thank you for your help.

Comment: To get rid of the initial space in each value, split on `#":\s*"` -- a colon followed by (optionally) any amount of whitespace.

Comment: @DaveYarwood Oops. I didn't notice the white space just after colon. I updated the answer.